# Luppp only plays half of my WAV soundfile

Tags: 18.04, sound, jack

I'm using [OpenAv Luppp](http://openavproductions.com/luppp/) to work with some wav file loops. However, when I copy them in, they are only played half. I tried doubling the length of the audio and it is play as it should. Am I missing some options?

Comment: What happens when you play the WAV files in another app, such as Audacity?

Comment: That's where they are imported from. The file is definitely correct. Right now I simply double the length of the sound files. And then it's played correctly